# Selecting only 3 first joined items with uniq attribute within each group grouped by group by clause

Tags: mysql, sql, join, greatest-n-per-group

I have got simple sql:

```
SELECT foos.*, bars.* FROM foos 
  LEFT JOIN bars ON bars.foo_id = foos.id
  WHERE foos.id = 1;
```

=>

```
+------------------------------------+
| foos.id | bars.id | bars.author_id |
+------------------------------------+
|    1    |    1    |       10       |
|    1    |    3    |       10       |
|    1    |    5    |       3        |
|    1    |    6    |       10       |
|    1    |    7    |       10       |
|    1    |    8    |       10       |
|    1    |    44   |       11       |
|    1    |    32   |       10       |
+------------------------------------+
```

Now I need to returned not all joined `bars` but only first three (slice) for each `bars.author_id`, so it could return something like this efficiently

```
+------------------------------------+
| foos.id | bars.id | bars.author_id |
+------------------------------------+
|    1    |    1    |       10       |
|    1    |    3    |       10       |
|    1    |    5    |       3        |
|    1    |    6    |       10       |
|    1    |    44   |       11       |
+------------------------------------+
```

Comment: This is a typo `LEFT JOIN bars ON bars.foo_id = bars.id`, isn't it?

Comment: This is a commonly asked question. Try the [greatest-n-per-group](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/greatest-n-per-group) tagged questions or the links on the right, under **Related**.

Comment: wow, cool! I didn't know how to name this technique

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i have a good solution for this:

```
For, selecting 1st 3 record within each group 
1) sorting the results asc/desc by applying `order by bars.id` within group_concat()
2) limiting the records by passing the 3rd parameter as the records to limit to SUBSTRING_INDEX(str,'match str','no of records to limit') 

SELECT foos.id, 
       SUBSTRING_INDEX(GROUP_CONCAT(bars.id
                       order by bars.id),',',3),
       bars.author_id

FROM foos LEFT JOIN bars ON bars.foo_id = foos.id

WHERE foos.id = 1
GROUP BY bars.author_id
```

The result would be :

```
+------------------------------------+
| foos.id | bars.id | bars.author_id |
+------------------------------------+
|    1    |    1,3,6    |       10   |
|    1    |    5        |       3    |
|    1    |    44       |       11   |
+------------------------------------+
```

Later, on application side you can explode it by ',' and use it.

Answer (score 1):

You could try:

```
SELECT f.*, b.* 
FROM foos f
LEFT JOIN (select b1.*
           from bars b1
           where 3 < (select count(*)
                      from bars bn 
                      where bn.foo_id = b1.foo_id and
                            bn.author_id = b1.author_id and
                            bn.id < b1.id)
           ) b
       ON b.foo_id = f.id
WHERE f.id = 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT 
      foos.*
    , bars.* 
FROM 
      foos 
  LEFT JOIN 
      bars 
    ON  bars.foo_id = foos.id
    AND bars.author_id <= COALESCE(
       ( SELECT b.author_id
         FROM bars b
         WHERE b.foo_id = foos.id
         ORDER BY b.author_id ASC
         LIMIT 0 OFFSET 2            --- one less than 3
       ), 2147483647              )
WHERE 
      foos.id = 1
```

An index on `bars( foo_id, author_id )` will help if it's slow.